# Does anything like Rails Engine exist for Laravel?

Tags: php, ruby-on-rails, ruby, laravel

Is there anything like Rails engines or similar for Laravel?

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/engines.html

Essentially what I'm aiming for is to have a single app with little "child" laravel apps contained within it and still have the ability to use the parent code as much as possible but still be able to override anything in the context of the child.

Hope this makes sense

Comment: Great question. I'm interested as well.

Answer (score 3):

On searching a bit, I stumbled upon Laravel's [package feature](http://laravel.com/docs/packages).

This question is already [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22307075/how-to-structure-a-platform-with-sub-apps-in-laravel-4) here on SO. It says, you need to make a kernel package as your basic project and then extend 'sub projects' from your git repository, it's easy way, as Laravel introduction says:

> "Packages might be anything from a great way to work with dates like Carbon, or an entire BDD testing framework like Behat."

With packages you can single out each feature on `composer.json` and load them one by one.

It's just like RoR's engine but obviously a different approach as they are two different frameworks.

Happy coding!

Comment: Yeah, that's right, it's `Package Development`  in Laravel.